# SilverStripe 3.1.x https - Is there a config option for setting the secure base URL for shared SSL?

Tags: security, url, ssl, config, silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1.x - Is there an option for setting the secure baseURL?

In **mysite/_config.php**, I have the following:

```
Director::forceSSL(array('/^admin/', '/^Security/'));
```

When visiting a URL which contains 'admin' or 'Security', SilverStripe uses https, which is great for people who have purchased a secuirty certificate for their domain.  However, in the case of those who are using shared SSL on a shared hosting platform, the base secure URL to the site might be completely different.

So whilst the non-secure base URL might be 
`http://www.example.com/`,

the secure base URL might be `https://123.45.67.89/example.com/`

How would I forceSSL for 'admin' and 'Security' and also specify the base secure URL, which is what would be required for some hosts when using a basic shared SSL cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you use `URLRewriting` for that? Any HTTPS request is redirected to the right domain...

For example for Apache, taken from https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache

```
# Rewrite secure requests properly in order to prevent SSL certificate warnings.
# E.g.: prevent `https://www.example.com` when your certificate only allows
# `https://secure.example.com`.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#     RewriteRule ^ https://example-domain-please-change-me.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>
```

Comment: I agree, letting the webserver do it is the best way to go here

Comment: Thanks colymba and Zauberfisch for confirming the best route.